# Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices and let $f(x)=$det$(xI-B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices and let $f(x)=$det$(xI-B)$ be. Show that $f(A)$ is invertible if and only if $A$ and $B$ have no common eigenvalues.

I'm trying to see minimal polynomial of matrix $A$ but I got stuck to prove that.

Comment: Do you mean $f(A)\not=0$?

Comment: Over a field, $\det(xA-B)\ne 0$ iff $A,B$ have no common eigenvalues. Now what's an eigenvalue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if $f(x)=\prod_{k=1}^n(x-\lambda_k(B))$ then
$$
\det f(A)=\det\prod_{k=1}^n(A-\lambda_k(B)\cdot I)=\prod_{k=1}^n\det(A-\lambda_k(B)\cdot I).
$$